# Matplotlib: adding legend for each column of numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Hi I have a numpy array

```
a = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (10,3))
```

I want to plot each of the columns with its own label

```
plt.plot(a, label = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
plt.legend()
```

How can I do that? The above is my tentative, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly shorter approach (because the handles are already present in the legend):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (10,3))

plt.plot(a)
plt.legend(['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)

```
l1,l2, l3 = plt.plot(a)
plt.legend((l1,l2, l3), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
```